# converting ObjectId as type:String from mongoexport back to type:ObjectId after ingesting into Mongo Database

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query

What has been done:

1. I have exported a collection from my database using mongoexport as CSV. I found that the _id field is exported as String (`ObjectId(5eeb6f8e0795936999a10110)`). Note missing `""`. It should be like this `ObjectId("5eeb6f8e0795936999a10110")`
2. I have done some text processing on the CSV file and made a new collection with exported `_id` as the new field (`display_id`).
3. I have imported the new collection using mongoimport.

Now the problem is `display_id` is imported as a String, not as mongo ObjectId.  How to convert this String to ObjectId?

I read [this article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-change-the-type-of-a-field-in-mongodb) where we can convert from String to Int but in my case, I think I also have to do some processing on String and then convert to ObjectId.

Comment: You'd simply find all documents in the collection and update each one individually. Using bulk writes will speed up the process.

Comment: what is your DB version ?